# pycrypto or libssl not found, decryption may be slow

Tags: wallet.dat

My wallet.dat file is corrupted and everytime i try to run Wallet QT client will shut down as unexpected error and i have no longer access at my wallet on this way.

I have tried to dump private keys through pywallet but everytime i execute commands it shows pywallet or libssl not found...

[image: Screenshot showing warning and error messages]

Actually i don't have much experience with this, Downloaded openssl and pycrypto then extracted both files to C:\Python27 , im doing this wrong if yes please help me to setup.

Comment: SC: https://prnt.sc/rufmpy

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows two messages:

There is a message

> `ERROR:root:Couldn't open wallet.dat/main`

It suggests you should close Bitcoin if it is already running. I would use Windows' task-manager to see if bitcoin-qt, bitcoind etc are running (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Windows-10 should bring up a menu from which you can select `task-manager`). You can close those processes from task manager if necessary.

Since your screenshot shows a second attempt without this error, it looks like you shut down Botcoin-qt OK and the command completed OK.

---

and

> `WARNING:root:pycrypto or libssl not found, decryption may be slow`

This is just a warning, it doesn't mean that the command won't work, just that it may take longer than normal.

The message suggests pywallet will use slow internal cryptographic functions if it doesn't have access to a fast external library of cryptographic functions.

---

So your `wallet.txt` file should show you the information you wanted to extract.